# Test mail not working while sending in drupal 7 MS outlook SMTP configuration

Tags: drupal-7, smtp, phpmailer, smtp-auth

I installed SMTP Authentication module on drupal 7. I tried to send test mail getting the below error,
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

Error sending e-mail. Will retry on cron run : SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host..
phpmailerException: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. in PHPMailer->SmtpConnect() (line 839 of /var/www/sites/all/modules/smtp/smtp.phpmailer.inc).

Here am using ms outlook mail for smtp authentication.

Any one fix my issue, Pls find the attached screenshots.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqFX4.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaPc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please add your details as per the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Let me know if this works for you or not.